# Can't access xsl data on Atom0.xsl

Tags: xslt

I'm using B1IF to create a simple webservice to get BusinessPartners from SAP try access data received on atom0.xsl (final atom).

This is my received data on atom:

[EDIT: broken link http:// pastebin.com/C59K01gz]

This is my atom0.xsl:

[EDIT: broken link http:// pastebin.com/nmJcn3Gd]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there just mising the root node in your xpath. Use the following as your template, instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/bfa:unbranch">
            <Msg xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/vpf:Header"/>
                    <Body>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/*"/>
                            <Payload Role="R" id="{$atom}">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="transform"/>
                            </Payload>
                    </Body>
            </Msg>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: U are saying i need to change<xsl:template name="transform"> to <xsl:template name="transform"  match="/bfa:unbranch"> on my atom0.xsl right?

Comment: Updated the template.. you also need to remove the slashes from copy-of statements..

Comment: I hope replacing your template with the one updated helps.. We can talk more on SO, though :)

Comment: yes this worked to acess data but now i need to change my webservice result to the content of atom4.xsl

Comment: I think worked but no, i cant acess to the data received on atom0.xsl

Comment: Where do you see the problem?